# unable to get the messages from the mqtt topic to ros topic. ||Mqtt to Ros bridge

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, ros, robotics, ros2

Issue: Trying to get mqtt messages from mqtt_topic to ros topic.
I am trying to control my robot which is in ros environment from the outside server using mqtt protocol. I got connected with the outside server. But i didn't get the messages from the mqtt_topic

[image]

I am currently using mqtt bridge package https://github.com/groove-x/mqtt_bridge
Please help me to overcome this issue or please recommend some other mqtt ros bridge packages.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Also please do not post images of text, they are hard to read, impossible for people who use screen readers and unsearchable. Post the actual text and format it with the toolbar

Comment: Please show `demo.launch` and the code you use to verify that nothing is received or the `rostopic echo` call you use instead. Your screenshot is not overly useful (and should be text as hardillb says).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.